# MySQL field name conflict

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table with 50 something fields each field contains the corresponding two character state name. I have this mysql_query when a state is selected

```
//$entry is state name abbr. Oregon = OR<br/>
//$cname and $zoneName aren't important.

'UPDATE stateCarriers SET '.$entry.'= 1 WHERE cname="'.$cname.'" AND zone="'.$zoneName.'"'
```

so I'm having an issue when `OR` is the `$entry` since mysql thinks it is the `OR` operator.

How do I solve this issue without changing the field name to something else?

Comment: it is almost certainly a quoting issue.  try double quotes

Comment: Try concatting \` characters around $entry

Comment: You can use back ticks to escape a name ... but I'm guessing that the table structure is not correct.  Using "data" for field names seems unlikely to be the correct approach.

Comment: @Randy should be backticks not double quotes... some info here: [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the backtick character, e.g.  `field`=1 to delimit the field.  This seems to work pretty well for me, although it was under slightly different circumstances.

Comment: yes `` `` that's what you mean ;) stack overflow converts to code ;)

Answer (score 0):

'UPDATE stateCarriers SET `'.$entry.'`= 1 WHERE cname="'.$cname.'" AND zone="'.$zoneName.'"'